# laravel NotReadableException in Decoder.php - Unable to read image from file

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I am getting this error. After searching the internet it looks like the issue could be with the `post_upload_size` and `post_size`, but that's not it.

I upload larger images that work fine, then this image that has 1.5MB is not working. It's like it's random. It works for some, but not for all images. Here's the full output.

Whoops, looks like something went wrong:

> 1/1 NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 46: Unable to read image from file (/tmp/phpVpVQeP).

```
in Decoder.php line 46
at Decoder->initFromPath('/tmp/phpVpVQeP') in AbstractDecoder.php line 293
at AbstractDecoder->init('/tmp/phpVpVQeP') in AbstractDriver.php line 64
at AbstractDriver->init('/tmp/phpVpVQeP') in ImageManager.php line 50
at ImageManager->make('/tmp/phpVpVQeP') in Facade.php line 215
at Facade::__callStatic('make', array('/tmp/phpVpVQeP')) in ProfileController.php line 251
at Image::make('/tmp/phpVpVQeP') in ProfileController.php line 251
at ProfileController->sendProfile(object(Request), 'klaughlin')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ProfileController), 'sendProfile'), array(object(Request), 'username' => 'klaughlin')) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('sendProfile', array(object(Request), 'username' => 'klaughlin')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ProfileController), object(Route), 'sendProfile') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(ProfileController), object(Route), object(Request), 'sendProfile') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController', 'sendProfile') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 708
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 710
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Cors.php line 18
at Cors->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Cors), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Here is my var_dump

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#30 (7) { ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> bool(false) ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(19) "20160212_124938.jpg" ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(1606199) ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpVpVQeP" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(9) "phpVpVQeP" } string(14) "1483214733.jpg" string(76) "/home/laughlindavid/public_html/mealog.com/public/profilepics/1483214733.jpg"
```

It is odd how it just does this with certain images.

Here is the code in my controller.

```
$image = Input::file('picture');
var_dump($image);
$filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
var_dump($filename);
$path = public_path('profilepics/' . $filename);
var_dump($path);

Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200)->save($path);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I've solved the problem after installing `imagick` driver and setting `driver` to `imagick` `(config/image.php)` instead of GD.

Answer (score 1):

This error may have many different solutions, but I'm hoping this will help someone out there. The short answer was that my php version which is 5.6 throws a gd.jpeg warning which probably caused it to not show as a gd resource when I did a var_dump in my intervention image Decoder.php file. Maybe using image Imagick driver instead of GD driver would have fixed this issue. BUT I USED THIS TO IGNORE THE WARNING, which PHP VERSION 1.7 now does automatically.

```
ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

So horray! My now all images uploaded consistently, but there was another issue I think related to this. My images had EXIF data in them which caused some of them to rotate automatically which was strange. Luckily Intervention Image has a method for this "orientate()" which I use when I create my image. Here's my new code in controller.

```
            $image = $picture;

            echo '<br>';
            $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $path = public_path('profilepics/' . $filename);


        $imageMoved = $image->move(public_path('profilepics'), $filename);

         ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
         error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

                Image::make($path)->resize(200,200)->orientate()->save($path);
```

I really hope this saves you the major time I spent reading through totally different issues throwing the same error. My advice would be to var dump the crap out of the files your errors are coming from and compare (at least for my case) the working images from the non-working ones. Peace and Happy Coding!

Comment: Note: I also ended up moving my uploaded image from the temp folder because I read that there might be issues with that.

Comment: I added the `gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 1` to the php.ini after the `[gd]`